# How to send email to submitter anytime webform modified

Tags: webforms

I have a webform page to submit data from authentic users. The moderator should see this to verify the data. When the moderator changes the submitted data, I want the system send an email to the submitter notifying the data has been changed.

How Can I do that. Is that any additional module(s) to handle that task?

Comment: means you want to send mail to moderator for the changes of form data?

Comment: no, send email to the original submitter

Comment: Have try by using [webform_rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module, where you can set event >> condition >> action to send mail.

Comment: yes, but i have a problem, it sends email to the moderator who modify the webform submission, not sending to the submitter of the data. In the action to send mail I use user:mail. What is the parameter to send to the submitter not the modifier?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I can send an email to the submitter by using [webform rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) module.

**Event:**
After a webform submission has been updated

**Condition:**
Data selector: form-id
Webforms: select the webform that i use

**Action:**
Send email:

To: `<?php print $data['components']['email']['value'][0]; ?>`

From: ...just leave it blank